# Since upgrading from 8.9.2 to 9.0.3 I cannot install custom modules

Tags: upgrading, 9

In Drupal 8.x I experimented with some modules and custom blocks, but whatever I do after upgrading to 9.0.3, the modules don't show up in the Extend menu. In the .info.yml file I changed the `core: 8.x` line to `core: 9`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using the new ish [core_version_requirement](https://www.drupal.org/node/3070687) key?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because 'core: 9.x' in info files is no longer supported. Please see this change record: https://www.drupal.org/node/3119415

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 9 doesn't use the *core* key anymore. Instead, it uses the *core_version_requirement* key. If the module is compatible with both Drupal 8 and Drupal 9, it should use the following lines.

```yaml
core: 8.x
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
```

Notice that `core: 8.x` isn't necessary anymore for versions after Drupal 8.7.7. If the module is compatible with Drupal 8.8 and higher versions, the first line of the following code isn't necessary.

```yaml
core: 8.x
core_version_requirement: ^8.8 || ^9
```

(To be compatible with Drupal 8.8 and higher versions, the module should not use any of the classes/methods/functions removed from Drupal 9, but this is a different story.)

#### Reference

- [Let Drupal know about your module with an .info.yml file](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/let-drupal-know-about-your-module-with-an-infoyml-file)